# Sql statement to find the count of records with dates less than today's date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field of date in mysql database table call dates which stores date in the format d-m-y.

I am looking for an sql statement to find the count of all the dates which are less than or equal to today's date. For example if today's date is 18-07-2017
and we have record in the dates table with dates such as 17-07-2017 ,18-07-2017,19-07-2017, the sql statement should output 2.

Can someone help.

Comment: Why are you storing them as strings instead of as `DATE` or `DATETIME`?

Comment: This is pretty basic SQL; have you tried anything?

Comment: Use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert the strings to dates. Then you can compare them with `TODAY()`.

Comment: Stop storing dates as strings, and use a real DATE type instead, and you won't have this issue. Format the dates when you SELECT them to whatever appearance you want, but store them as DATE values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform the value to a date and make the comparison:

```
select count(*)
from t
where str_to_date(stupid_date_column, '%d-%m-%Y') <= curdate();
```

Then fix your table so the date is stored correctly:

```
update t
    set stupid_date_column = date_format(str_to_date(stupid_date_column, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d');

alter table t modify stupid_date_column date;
```